# How to add a new post with tumblrAPI V2 oauth php

Tags: post, oauth, addition, tumblr

```
 $request_data = http_build_query(
        array(
            'oauth_token' => 'xxx',
            'api_key' => 'xxx',
            'type' => 'hello',
            'title' => 'this is title',
            'body' => 'this is body',
            'generator' => 'API example'
        )
 );

 // Send the POST request (with cURL)
 $c = curl_init('http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/abc.tumblr.com/post');
 curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_data);
 curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $result = curl_exec($c);
 $status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
 curl_close($c);
```

but not run...
Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not sending any OAuth Authorization header which is required. This is a little bit of a tricky task since it requires that you also create a signature from the parameters and oauth tokens so as a starter you might want to read this documentation: http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/

Alternatively there are some OAuth PHP libraries out there which will do that part for you: http://oauth.net/code/